# Get google drive file download URL

Tags: google-drive-api

Following the [Hello world application](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) and using the File Picker, I am able to get a google drive file information.

I would like to get the download url of this file (it is a binary file) in a my web application.

Is there any way to get it with the new javascript sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The Picker returns the id string. Use this to get the item object (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) which will contain a variety of download URL's depending on your precise requirement.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this currently, but it looks like I need to set up credentials and auth against the Google Drive API as well as the picker API. Without doing this I get an error on the GET request. This seems very bloated and inefficient. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "bloated and inefficient"? It's generally good OAuth practice to have fine grained scopes so your app only requests the permissions it needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "bloated and inefficient"? It's generally good OAuth practice to have fine grained scopes so your app only requests the permissions it needs.

Comment: I mean having to potentially use 2 APIs to get one URL is long winded. Especially if you have to set up two apps, two sets of credentials etc. The picker API should return a download URL instead of just a preview one.

Problem I'm having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412969/how-to-get-a-direct-download-url-from-google-picker-javascript-api