# How to get a direct download URL from Google Picker JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a direct download URL for a file using Google's Picker API so that I can choose a file and pass this URL to server side code to download and store a copy of the item on the server.

I'm able to authorize through the picker API and get info of a picked file including the file name and preview URL (which is confusingly referred to as simply "A URL to this item" in the JSON response docs: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/results)

I noticed that there is a post about using the Drive API to get a direct download URL here: [Get google drive file download URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519084/get-google-drive-file-download-url)

However when I do this in my picker callback function (based on the docs here: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

I get an error of:

```
 "Project [number here] is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Drive API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project=[project number here] then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
```

I have the API enabled in my developer console and the URL added to the JS allowed origins.

The documentation is very confusing and there seems to be 3 versions of the REST API to use with Drive which is based on an gapi.auth2 object whereas the picker api uses gapi.auth object.

I'm not sure if I need to authenticate again using the Google Drive API before performing the GET request. This all seems very messy and I believe there must be an easier approach for what is a simple request!

My picker callback function:

```
  pickerCallback: function(data) {
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
      var fileName = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
      var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
      var docId = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
      var request = null;

      gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
        request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
          'fileId': docId
        });
        request.execute(function(resp){
          console.log(resp);
        });
      });


     //Write upload details to page
     //Populate hidden field
    }
```

Developer console screen - The first app is the picker API the second is for the Drive API:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the simple callback implementation shown in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld). Notice that `url` was initialized before the `if` statement:

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        }
        var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}
```

Also, in authorizing, set the `AppId` value and choose the user account with the app's current OAuth 2.0 token. Note that the `AppId` set and the client ID used for authorizing access to a user's files must be contained in the same app. Then, after successfully obtaining the `fileId`, you can then send request using [`files.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get). By default, this responds with a [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) in the response body which includes `downloadUrl`.

For additional insights, see this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258140/download-file-from-google-picker-api-in-rails).

Comment: I'm not sure why declaring the URL before the IF will help resolve the issue as I'm already able to get this URL from picker. The problem is with the auth for the get request as I'm getting a 403 error.

I tried the approach mentioned in your linked post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342256/1644178 and I get the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about authorizing and the user's files having to be within the same app. I have posted my dev console screen in the original question. There are two apps, one for picker and one for drive. Do both of these need separate authorisation?